# Having real problems with Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have a dedicated server with WHM and cPanel. It already has composer installed on it.

I'm trying to run the following php lines in a webpage:

```
  require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

  // Configure API key authorization: JWT
  $config = \Swagger\Client\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('Authorization', '[my api key]');

  $apiInstance = new \Swagger\Client\Api\MessagesApi(
      new \GuzzleHttp\Client(),
      $config
  );
```

I've created a `composer.json` in the `public_html` folder and put the following in it:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": { "Swagger\\Client\\" : "lib/" }
    }
}
```

And then I ran `composer update` in the terminal which seemed to install the dependencies and all the relevant files.

It's seeing the autoload.php file but I'm still getting a class not found error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Swagger\Client\Configuration' not found in /home/mywebsite/public_html/converter/sms.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/mywebsite/public_html/converter/sms.php on line 9
```

I've been at this for 4 hours now. What am I doing wrong? I can't find anything online that will guide me in the right direction.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that `Configuration.php` is missing in you `lib` folder, within your projects root folder.

Comment: also the autoloader assumes the file has the same name and same casing as the class, so if Configuration is in configuration.php it wont work

Comment: If that's your complete `composer.json` file, where are you requiring those packages?

Comment: How did you install Swagger? If you used Composer for this (which you should), why did you add an additional autoloader path for it?

Answer (score 0):

In Composer Basic Usage documentation about [autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) it says

> For libraries that specify autoload information, Composer generates a vendor/autoload.php file. You can include this file and start using the classes that those libraries provide without any extra work

So, as @NicoHaase said in the comments, if you installed Swagger with Composer (adding a [require key](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#the-require-key) and running `composer update`, for example) you don't need to specify the autoload path to Swagger in `composer.json`.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What makes you think that this resolves the problem?

Comment: I think I've misunderstood the original author's question. Sorry and thanks for pointing that out. I edited my answer. If it's not good enough, please let me know. I'm getting used to responding to StackOverflow questions.